# Problems aligning text in a table using string formatting

Tags: python

So i'm having trouble with a task. I'm supposed to create a chart which shows the converted numbers between Celsius and Fahrenheit. They want the Celsius to range from 40 to -40. I also get to know that Fahrenheit  = 32+celsius*9/5. Now I managed to write the number 40 to -40 from top to bottom. But i'm having trouble converting celsius to fahrenheit and printing it at the same time on the side of celsius. The chart should look something like this:

```
 + Celsius ------ Fahrenheit
 + 40 ----------- 104    
 + 39 ----------- 102,2
 + etc. --------- etc.
```

My current code is:

```
print("Celsius to Fahrenheit")
print("=======================")
print("Celsius\t    Fahrenheit")

for f in range(40,-41,-1):
    print(f)
for c in range(104,-41,-1):
    print(32 + c * 9 / 5)
```

Now this makes the numbers for Fahrenheit to just add below celsius. How do I make them go to the other side  under the text Fahrenheit? Sorry for bad formatting and spelling. First time posting here.

I'm doing this in iPython Notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense - you're calculating Fahrenheit over a different range to Celsius. Try:

```
for c in range(40, -41, -1): # iterate over Celsius
    f = (c * (9 / 5)) + 32 # calculate Fahrenheit from Celsius
    print("{0:d}\t{1:.1f}".format(c, f)) # print both in one line, tab-separated
```

You can modify the string being `format`ted to give the exact formatting you need - see [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

*N.B. Based on your `print` syntax I have assumed Python 3.x - you will need to modify slightly for 2.x to account for integer division.*

Comment: Ok so this cleared up a lot for me. I've not used .format alot before, really new to Python. Unfortunately it now only prints out one line with converted numbers, that being -40 and -40. Do I have to add something to make it continue?

Comment: I can only assume your indentation is incorrect - [it's important in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming), copy the snippet in my answer exactly.

Comment: Worked now, guess i copied it wrong the first time :)